# Динамически расширяемая БД

Tags: php, mysql

Столкнулся с проблемой создания динамической базы данный на MySQL. Пробовал разные методы, разные подходы. Хочется реализовать по простой логике - если текущий ID'шник есть, то обновить данные, если же новый пользователь, то завести запись (новую строку).

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $count = $_GET['count'];

    if (EXISTS(SELECT id FROM views WHERE id = 1)) {
        mysqli_query($relation, "UPDATE `views` SET `count` = $count WHERE `id` = $id");
    } else {
        mysqli_query($relation, "INSERT INTO views (count) VALUES ($count)");
    }
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score -2):

решил таким вот образом:

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $count = $_GET['count'];

    $result = "SELECT id FROM views WHERE id = $id";
    $query = mysqli_query($relation, $result);

    if (mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        mysqli_query($relation, "UPDATE views SET count = $count WHERE id = $id");
    } else {
        mysqli_query($relation, "INSERT INTO views (count) VALUES ($count)");
    }
```

Comment: То бишь если в `$_GET['count']` передать два миллиарда, то оно в БД так и запишется?

Comment: Бред.. вам в первом комментарии к вопросу дан ответ... `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: @Jour а вдруг это не ключ?